# Using discord.FFmpegPCMAudio() with youtube_dl results in file not found from ffmpeg

Tags: python, bots

I'm creating a bot for Discord in Python, when I run the script, in the chat I type for example "!play...", the bot enters the voice channel and then in the terminal it comes out saying that "INFO discord.player ffmpeg process 22136 successfully terminated with return code of 4294967294.", that is, the ffmpeg process is terminated and then the bot doesn't play anything. Could someone please help me solve this problem, here is the code part of the play command:

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play_song(ctx, *, song):
    query = f'{song} official video'
    ydl_options = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': True, 'extract_flat': True}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_options) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False)
        if 'entries' in info:
            url = info['entries'][0]['url']
            title = info['entries'][0]['title']
            
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice
            if not voice_channel:
                await ctx.send("Devi essere in un canale vocale per poter riprodurre una canzone!")
                return
            vc = await voice_channel.channel.connect()
            
            await ctx.send(f"Inizio a riprodurre '{title}'.")
            
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url))

            songs_queue.append((url, title))
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nessun risultato trovato per la canzone specificata.")
```

**Stderr as follow:**

```
Error while running ffmpeg.
Here is some information: ffmpeg version N-111719-gb98ee1a355-20230808 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.196_227d99d)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-
libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20230808
  libavutil      58. 15.100 / 58. 15.100
  libavcodec     60. 23.100 / 60. 23.100
  libavformat    60. 10.100 / 60. 10.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 10.100 /  9. 10.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /
11.100
libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[in#0 @ 000001ef8f484300] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file 9QZMjFC_RgY.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory
```

**Python Stack Trace:**

```
Traceback: NoneType: None
```

Comment: You're on Windows, I assume -- on UNIX that isn't a valid exit status at all

Comment: Anyhow -- if you capture the stderr emitted by ffmpeg, what does it report?

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question itself. (If you have a Python stack trace, include that too).

Comment: Sure, it appears that FFmpeg cannot open the specified input file, here's the stderr: "Error while running ffmpeg. Details: ffmpeg version N-111719-gb98ee1a355-20230808 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 13.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.196_227d99d) configuration: ... [abbreviated config] ... libswresample 4. 11.100 / 4. 11.100 libpostproc 57. 2.100 / 57. 2.100 [in#0 @ 000001ef8f484300] Error opening input file 9QZMjFC_RgY Error opening input files: No such file or directory"

As for the Python stack trace, unfortunately only this comes out:
"Traceback:
NoneType: None"

Comment: Were there really no newlines in the original output, as you pasted it into the question? Part of why I asked for an edit instead of a comment was to preserve the formatting of the original logs and error; because comments destroy formatting, pasting your content first info a comment and then from the comment into the question loses information.

Comment: Not directly. I don't run Discord, I don't run Discord bots -- but this is a stronger question than it was before, so it should be easier for someone else who does have that background to help you. If the problem were reproducible _without_ the discord module, that would open it up to a wider audience; you can of course test if you can cause the same issue from a script that just uses youtube_dl (and perhaps directly passes the result to the ffmpeg executable without the discord library involved).